# Separate archive template to show posts and CPT by same category/taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, archives

I have archives for posts and another for reviews which are working fine, try as I might though I'm struggling to have a separate archive under the URL /content/[category]

that pulls both posts and CPT for that taxonomy/category. Is this even possible with WP as well as pagination on the template?